# How do I make my navigation bar remain on top of page while scrolling?

Tags: html, css

Here is the HTML code

```
<div id="header" class="grid_12">
<h6>DCHOST - Brought to you by <a href="http://www.dt.co.uk" target="_blank">
DataConnectivity.co.uk
</a></h6>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Hosting</li>
                <li>Domain Names</li>
                <li>Lates News</li>
                <li>About us</li>
                <li>Contact Us</li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- ends header grid 12 -->
```

CSS

```
#header {
color: #848484;
height: 70px;
width: 100%;
font-size: small;
font-style: oblique;
text-align: center;
background: #333333;}

#header h6 {
max-height: 3px;
font-size: 10px;
text-align:left;
}

#header li {
font-weight: 800;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-style: normal;
display: inline}
```

I would like my nav bar to remain fixed on top of page. However, every time I change position to fixed, the bar completely disappears. I have no idea why its doing this? 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4J6M/) of the code above.

Comment: Don't see a problem http://jsfiddle.net/J2tK5/

Comment: Appreciate your help. I had trouble due to having an image below which kept overriding it. But with your advice and z-index I managed to solve it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to position the header with `top: 0;` and set the `z-index` to be higher than all other elements.

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

This will also add compatibility between browsers.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4J6M/1/)**

Comment: Awesome, completely forgot I needed to assign a top position. I also had trouble with my image below overriding it but using z-index along with your advice solved the problem. So thanks again for your help!

Comment: Forgot to mention the `z-index` i'll update my answer.